# Google DialogFlow - How to make a call to phone number outside of USA

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm looking for a solution to make a call to a phone number in Asia from DialogFlow.

Currently Dialogflow Phone Gateway is still in Beta and it only support US.

Is there any solution to my use-case?

Answer (score 0):

yes, take a look at this page, it gives 3 options and ways to do it. https://cogint.ai/3-methods-for-connecting-a-phone-call-to-dialogflow/